# How to use @ViewById for an inflated view outside of @EActivity(R.layout.activity_x)

Tags: android, expandablelistview, layout-inflater, android-annotations, findviewbyid

I am using `Android Annotations 3.1` in my project in Android Studio and I am using an Expandable List View.

I am adding a header to my list like this:

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_view_header, null);
txt_user = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.txt_user);
txt_user.setText(" ... "); 
mExpandableListView.addHeaderView(header);
```

**Question**:

How can I use `@ViewById` to set my `TextView` to:

  - avoid using findViewById

  - changing  its text

  - and then adding that as a header during:

```
@AfterViews
protected void init() {
 ....

}
```

If I do this inside my Activity when using my text view inside init:

```
@ViewById
TextView txt_user;
```

It gives null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create a custom view like this :

```
@EViewGroup(R.layout.list_view_header)
public class MyHeader extends LinearLayout {

     @ViewById(R.id.txt_user)
     protected TextView mTextView;

     public void setText(String text) {
         mTextView.setText(text);
     }
     public MyHeader(Context context) {
         super(context);
     }
}
```

Then, in your `Activity`, write this :

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_xxx)
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyHeader mHeader;

    @AfterViews
    protected void init() {
        mHeader = MyHeader_.build(this);
        mHeader.setText("...");
        mExpandableListView.addHeaderView(mHeader);
    }
}
```

Comment: I created MyHeader.class but it gives error: `Cannot find method value` at line `@ViewGroup(R.layout.list_view_header)`. I am not sure but maybe it has to do with the @ViewGroup Annotation or imports ?

Comment: Sorry, it's `@EViewGroup` instead of `@ViewGroup`. I updated my answer.

Comment: You can even move the `setText` call to `MyHeader` constructor and remove the `setText` method from the class if the text does not change later.

Comment: Thanks man it worked, I also had to add a constructor to my class and implement: `@Override protected void onLayout(...`. Now that i watched your example I can understand better the documentation about this part :)

Comment: I had a problem when tried to do the same thing but not inside an Activity but inside a Fragment. Can you try if that works for you if you implement that in fragment. It adds a view as header(i can click that) but its empty. Thanks

Comment: Don't worry man there was a problem with Android Studio, after adding some code and removing it, now its OK :)

Comment: @WonderCsabo I tried that and it gives me NullPointerException

Comment: Sorry, you should initialize in an `@AfterViews` annotated method, not a constructor. The injected `View`s are not yet available in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To use a view signed with @ViewGroup within a layout, you need to implement the constructors that take AttributSet in its class.

> NOTE: Remember to use the generated class that has a _ (underline) at the end.
>   She who must be declared in the layout xml.